# Delphi HTTPClient Unicode mapping issue

Tags: delphi, encoding, httpclient

Using System.Net.URLClient, System.Net.HttpClient from Delphi Sydney 10.4:

Downloading from certain sites east of Germany -

```
Result := GV.HTTPClient.Get(URL).ContentAsString;
```

results in EEncodingError "No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page."

All of these sites have:

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250"

instead of UTF-8

How do I handle this properly?
Something to do with AcceptCharset?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a charset specified in the HTTP response's `Content-Type` header? I'm betting HTTPClient is not looking for the charset in the HTML in the response's body. You may have to use `ContentStream` instead of `ContentAsString` and then decode the raw bytes manually.